# Installing GRUB2 to a USB drive as a backup bootloader

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, grub2

I want to install GRUB2 onto a drive with no iso on the drive, but as a secondary bootloader. I'm using archlinux and want a backup that doesn't have to be hard installed on my machine. How would I go about this, I can't find any methods online so far to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Install GRUB Bootloader on a Pen Drive or an External Harddisk](https://medium.com/@shivamsaxena2206/install-grub-bootloader-on-a-pen-drive-or-an-external-harddisk-a19584aa1ddf)

1. Install the grub utility using the following commands.

   ```
   sudo apt updpate
   sudo apt install grub-common
   ```
2. Find out the external device name, it's assumed here to be `sdb`.
3. Create an EFI partition using a disk utility such as Gparted.
   You should have 2 partitions:

   ```
    /dev/sdb1 : for UEFI boot
    /dev/sdb2 : This same EFI partition for EFI (Legacy) boot
   ```
4. Mount these two partitions.

   ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot/efi
   ```
5. Mount other required locations for GRUB to work:

   ```
    sudo mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
    sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
    sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```
6. Change the root to the mounted path:

   ```
    sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
7. Install GRUB on the external device:

   ```
    sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
   ```
8. Exit from the root shell using Ctrl+D
9. Unmount :

   ```
    sudo umount /mnt/proc
    sudo umount /mnt/dev
    sudo umount /mnt/sys
   ```
10. Turn off the computer and try to boot from the USB.
    You should see the grub terminal.

More details can be found in the linked article.